# How to extract text using regex in Python?

Tags: python, regex

I got a question how to extract some text using python regex.
I would like to do what I want using regex only not using the module for HTML such like a bs4.

it's example text as follow .

```
tr_range =

<tr>
    <td class="table-basic-l">
        Resolution
    </td>
    <td class="table-basic-l">
        Horizontal Frequency (kHz)
    </td>
    <td class="table-basic-l">
        Vertical Frequency (Hz)
    </td>
</tr>
```

I'd like to extract all texts under td elements like as Resolution, Horizontal Frequency (kHz), Vertical Frequency (Hz) using regex only.

I am trying to exclude start of all td elements but it's not that so easy for me so far.

Comment: You just want the text or an arry with the <td> texts in it?

Comment: I do not condone this summoning of Cthulhu.

Comment: just want text not any attribute

Comment: You should really use HTMLParser.

Comment: yeah i am able to solve this using HTML parser, but i want to know if it is possible to use regex

Comment: Seriously, just use Beautiful Soup. Don't waste your time or others'. https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the text with removing the html tags with regex like this (**works only for tables (tr and td tags)**):

```
import re

html='<tr>'\
    '<td class="table-basic-l">'\
    '    Resolution'\
    '</td>'\
    '<td class="table-basic-l">'\
    '    Horizontal Frequency (kHz)'\
    '</td>'\
    '<td class="table-basic-l">'\
    '    Vertical Frequency (Hz)'\
    '</td>'\
'</tr>'

print(re.sub("<[/]*t.*?>", "", html))
```

Comment: you almost approched, but what if there is < or > in the text ?

Comment: Then use Beautiful Soup.

Comment: @Cho shouldn't be a problem see here: regexr.com/42i67

Comment: @Cho if you have only <tr> and <td> elements, then my edit might help you?

Comment: yes of course it is! actually i was shocked seeing your code.

Comment: @Cho why shocked? :-D

Comment: cause it is way better than i thought